# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to run my code and I'm getting this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\JOSHUA\Documents\ypgforum\myproject\boards\models.py", line 13, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\JOSHUA\Documents\ypgforum\myproject\boards\models.py", line 16, in Topic
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

This is the models.py it pointed to:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    board = models.ForeignKey(Board, related_name='topics')
    starter = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='topics')
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to specify what should happen when the object the foreign key points to is deleted; this is the `on_delete` parameter. See the [`ForeignKey` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey):

> A many-to-one relationship. Requires two positional arguments: the class to which the model is related and the `on_delete` option.

and the [`ForeignKey.on_delete` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete):

> When an object referenced by a ForeignKey is deleted, Django will emulate the behavior of the SQL constraint specified by the `on_delete` argument.

Pick one from the available options (`models.CASCADE`, `models.PROTECT`, `models.SET_NULL`, `models.SET_DEFAULT`, `models.SET()` or `models.DO_NOTHING`)

The parameter is *required* as of Django 2.0. In previous Django versions, the argument was optional and defaulted to `models.CASCADE`.

If you were used to the old behaviour, just set it to the old default:

```
board = models.ForeignKey(Board, models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
starter = models.ForeignKey(User, models.CASCADE, related_name='topics')
```